# Extracting saturated sub neighborhoods from neighborhoods of level set in compact quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $q:X\to Y$ be a quotient map of topological spaces, and $X$ a compact space (we can assume it's Hausdorff, though this is probably unnecessary). Now, suppose we have $y\in Y$, and $U\subset X$ is an open containing $q^{-1}\{y\}$. I claim that there exists some saturated neighborhood $V$ such that $q^{-1}\{y\}\subset V\subset U$.

My only intuition for this is the tube lemma, which applies when $q$ is a projection from a product of two topological spaces. However, this doesn't seem to generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether the map $q$ is closed because of the criterion in Thereom 1.4.12 of Ryszard Engelking’s “General topology” 
(see below). Since $X$ is compact, if $Y$ is Hausdorff then the answer is positive, because any continuous map $q:X\to Y$ is closed.

[image]